# Two EXTRA_MESSAGE from Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Can i have two extra messages on `Intent` that i can pass on another `Activity`? If yes, how does it work?

this is what I did:

```
Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, Start.class);
String message = o.getName();
String messages = o.getPath();
intent3.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);   
intent3.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, messages);  
startActivity(intent3);`
```

and on the `Activity` that will receive the message:

```
Intent intent3 = getIntent();
String message = intent3.getStringExtra(Browse.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
String messages = intent3.getStringExtra(Browse.EXTRA_MESSAGE);`
```

Comment: no. bundle (or in this case intent that acts as a proxy) works like an associative array, it can have only one value per key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the KEY:

```
Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, Start.class);
String message = o.getName();
String messages = o.getPath();
intent3.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);   
intent3.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_TWO, messages); 
startActivity(intent3);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!
I fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly like that, but it is easy to send multiple values. The first parameter to putExtra or getStringExtra is a key into a map of values so it must be unique. As long as you use a different key for each value you can put as many as you want in the intent.

For example:

```
Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, Start.class);
String message = o.getName();
String messages = o.getPath();
intent3.putExtra("name", message);   
intent3.putExtra("path", messages);  
startActivity(intent3);

Intent intent3 = getIntent();
String message = intent3.getStringExtra("name");
String messages = intent3.getStringExtra("path");`
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem the way you have them. You need separate `key`s for each value. So for example

```
intent3.putExtra("msg1", message);   
intent3.putExtra("msg2", messages);
```

then in your receiving `Activity` you can get them using the above `key`s. But you can add as many `Extra` values as you want.

Comment: Wow! Well, that was stupid of me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Two different keys and messages will do it

```
  Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, Start.class);
    String message = o.getName();
    String messages = o.getPath();
    intent3.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE1, message);   
    intent3.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE2, messages); 
    startActivity(intent3);
```